# Slimframework 3 Redirect not working in controller

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am having a redirect issue with slim v3.11.0. When I call for a redirect in a route or from middleware it works as expected. However, when I call it from my controller it doesn't redirect nor error out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

*Ref https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/upgrade.html#changes-to-redirect

**route example (works)**

```
$app->get('/login/', function ($request, $response, $args) use($app) {
    return $response->withRedirect('/new-url');
});
```

**middleware example  (works)**

```
$auth = function ($request, $response, $next) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['Account'])) {
        return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/new-url/');
    }
};
```

**controller example  (no worky)**

```
$app->get('/login/', function ($request, $response, $args) use($app) {
    return (new Login($app))->TestLoginRedirect();
});

 ....

class Login {

     protected $App;

    public function __construct($app){
          $this->App = $app;
    }

    public function TestLoginRedirect(){
       return $this->App->getContainer()->response->withRedirect('/new-url');
    }
}
```

**Other redirect snippet tries**

```
return $this->App->getContainer()->response->withStatus(301)->withHeader('Location', '/new-url/');
return $this->App->redirect('/', '/new-url/');
```

Comment: aren't you missing a return in the controlller example? *$app->get('/login/', function* should probably return the result from *TestLoginRedirect*

Comment: i updated the example to return. still no luck

Comment: Could you update your post with the updated example code?

Comment: you are not returning the redirectResponse in the controller

Comment: @Dymen1,@zedling - I have updated the post the return in the controller and the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller example the route callback must return the response object, but it's not returning anything. It should be changed to:

```
$app->get('/login/', function ($request, $response, $args) use($app) {
    return (new Login($app))->TestLoginRedirect();
});
```